# Migrate Magento 1 design in Magento 2

Tags: magento

I am migrating a Magento 1 store to Magento 2 version. But client was the same design to use in Magento 2. Is there any technique available which can convert Magento 1 theme into Magento 2 theme or I need to create the Magento 2 theme from scratch?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is necessary to create a theme from scratch by the new requirement of Magento2.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of Magento 1 and Magento 2 is different. So Magento1's theme will not work in Magento 2.

Ask the vendor for the same theme in Magento 2.